Helm charts using a default yaml in values.yaml and the toYaml function not overriding correctly
I have a Helm chart and in the values.yaml file, I have a default securityContext defined that follows the restricted PSS.
By default, I want the user to use the restricted PSS, but I also want them to be able to modify it if required.
Heres the relevant section of my values.yaml:
security:
  containerSecurityContext:
    privileged: false
    allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
    # readOnlyRootFilesystem:
    runAsNonRoot: true
    runAsUser: 10001
    runAsGroup: 10001
    fsGroup: 10001
    capabilities:
      drop:
      - ALL
      add:
      - "NET_BIND_SERVICE"
    seccompProfile:
      type: "RuntimeDefault"

And here is where this is used in my chart:
      containers:
        - name: {{ include "chart.name" . }}
          {{- with .Values.security.containerSecurityContext }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml . | nindent 12 }}
          {{- end }}
          {{- with .Values.image }}
          image: {{ printf "%s/%s:%s" (required "An image.registry value is required!" .registry) (required "An image.repository value is required!" .repository) (required "An image.tag value is required!" .tag) | quote }}
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .pullPolicy }}

Using the default value in within the values.yaml is fine, but when setting a value to use, I get some unexpected behaviour.
When I set only 1 of the fields within the security.containerSecurityContext definition, only that 1 value is set and all the others remain as the default, but what I actually want is, if the user defines ANYTHING within the security.containerSecurityContext definition, then I don't want ANY of the default values being used, I want ONLY the user's set values being used.
So currently, the behaviour is this:
helm template . --set security.containerSecurityContext.runAsUser=1
      containers:
        - name: release-name
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            capabilities:
              add:
              - NET_BIND_SERVICE
              drop:
              - ALL
            fsGroup: 10001
            privileged: false
            runAsGroup: 10001
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1      // The value is set, but the others still remain the same
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault

But really, the output I want should be:
      containers:
        - name: release-name
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1          // I want only the users definition to be used

This behaviour is not a bug or anything, it makes sense, I just don't want my chart to behave in this way and I'm not sure how I achieve what I want.
My first thought is to have a helper in _helpers.tpl that contains the defaults I want, then to use default and toYaml in order to use this config by default, but I'm not sure that is the best approach.
EDIT:
Just to make this clearer, I can see the same behaviour when using a custom values.yaml.
custom-values.yaml
security:
  containerSecurityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
    runAsGroup: 0

Output of helm template -f custom-values.yaml:
      containers:
        - name: release-name
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            capabilities:
              add:
              - NET_BIND_SERVICE
              drop:
              - ALL
            fsGroup: 10001
            privileged: false
            runAsGroup: 0          // This gets set correctly
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 0           // This gets set correctly
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault

This is what I want the output to be:
      containers:
        - name: release-name
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
            runAsGroup: 0
            // I want ONLY the values defined by the user

I hope this makes it clearer in showing the behaviour I want. A user can supply values within a yaml file or otherwise, and the containerSecurrityContext block is placed (as is) into the securityContext definition of the container, removing any other values that are set by default, without the user needing to explicitly unset the other values by setting them to nil.

From Deleting a default key:

If you need to delete a key from the default values, you may override the value of the key to be null, in which case Helm will remove the key from the overridden values merge.

If you need to set/unset several settings I'd use custom values.yaml files as opposed to set multiple parameters using --set - or a combination of both, depending on your case. Using too many CLI parameters can get messy, and you need to be careful with special characters.
Example
Consider the following template and values file:
configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
  myvalue: "Hello World"
  {{- if .Values.favorite }}
  favorite: |
    {{- toYaml .Values.favorite | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}

values.yaml (default)
favorite:
  drink: coffee
  food: pizza

values.no-food.yaml (food is not set)
favorite:
  drink: coffee
  food: null # key will be deleted

Running helm template with the default values:
> helm template ./example02

---
# Source: example02/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: release-name-configmap
data:
  myvalue: "Hello World"
  favorite: |
    drink: coffee
    food: pizza

Running helm template with values.no-food.yaml:
> helm template ./example02 --values ./example02/values.no-food.yaml

---
# Source: example02/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: release-name-configmap
data:
  myvalue: "Hello World"
  favorite: |
    drink: coffee

Running helm template with --set ...:
> helm template ./example02 --set "favorite.drink=null"

---
# Source: example02/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: release-name-configmap
data:
  myvalue: "Hello World"
  favorite: |
    food: pizza

Removing the favorite section:
> helm template ./example02 --set "favorite=null"

---
# Source: example02/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: release-name-configmap
data:
  myvalue: "Hello World"


Thanks for your answer Rui, I am only using --set to demonstrate setting 1 value, its the behaviour of setting values within the yaml structure and only using those that I want. I will edit my question to make this clearer.

@Mo0rBy with or without the --set option, the behaviour is the same. For example, if you have a default object with 10 non-null properties and need to remove some, you'll have to set them to null.

@Mo0rBy how dynamic does your solution need to be? If you have a limited number of securityContext configurations consider creating a different values.yaml file for each, such as values-foo.yaml and values-bar.yaml and let the developer decide if he/she wants to use foo or bar configuration.

I am expecting the users of my charts to understand Kubernetes at a minimum, so they should know what options are available within a securityContext definition, but  I am assuming they may not have deep knowledge about Helm and that they can unset values by setting them to nil.
I want them to be able to create their own values files with whatever config they want, and this includes using their own securityContext definition without having to unset values, I want them to define a securityContext, and that securityContext to just get placed into the resulting yaml.

ah, so there is no way to get this behaviour without setting things to nil?

@Mo0rBy yes I understood that you want to make your developer's life easier, but the thing is: they need to have at least a minimum understanding of how to set and override values in Helm. They are probably not stupid, so just tell them that they need to set a property to null in order to remove the default value :-)

ah, so there is no way to get this behaviour without setting things to nil? - I don't think so, that's how Helm is designed. And if you ask me, I do like the fact it is designed this way because it is simple to use and override only the values we want.

If this is the case, then my thinking is that I can define a template function with the default securityContext within it, and use the default function to set that as the default, and still allow users to add whatever yaml they want. Thanks a lot, this has really helped me!

That's up to you, but I feel you're adding unnecessary complexity. Have some faith in the developers and tell them or document how to remove or override values, it's not rocket science :-)
